# How to figure basis for XOM (ExxonMobil) shares when XON (Exxon) was bought in 1985

Tags: stocks, income-tax, stock-analysis, dividends

I bought Exxon (XON) in March of 1985, 39.6649 shares @ 49.35/share with reinvestment of dividend income. I'm attempting to determine my basis of 100 shares deposited with Fidelity in 1992. I was going to try to calculate it by using posted dividends between those dates to calculate increased share counts (and account for the 2 for 1 split in 1987).

However, I can't find any historic prices for Exxon that make sense. All the historic prices I can find online have values between $6 and $15 for that period (?!).

Can someone explain whether these historic prices are supposed to account for multiple splits and the Mobil acquisition too? Or where I might find actual share prices.

Comment: To my understanding the reported share price would be adjusted for all historical stock splits. XOM has had 3 2-for-1 splits since 1985. You would need to multiply the reported share price value from 1985 by 8 (or 2 x 2 x 2) to get a contemporaneous price.

Answer (score 1):

ExxonMobil helpfully offers a PDF download with their dividend and split history back to 1911 (!) on their investor's [page](https://corporate.exxonmobil.com/Investors/Investor-relations/Dividend-information) (scroll to end).

Using this dividend and split history and a monthly price history, you should be able to calculate basis to a reasonable approximation. See also this [article](https://www.nj.com/business/2012/01/biz_brain_determining_the_cost.html) on calculating basis for DRIP investing.